# Spark exception - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/CatalystConf

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Whenever I call `spark.read.format` it shows `NoClassDefFoundError`.

```
scala> val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED").csv("hdfs://hadoopurl/test.csv")
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/CatalystConf
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.analyzer$lzycompute(HiveSessionState.scala:60)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.analyzer(HiveSessionState.scala:59)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:69)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:67)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:50)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:63)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.baseRelationToDataFrame(SparkSession.scala:389)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:146)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:415)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:352)
  ... 48 elided
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystConf
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  ... 58 more
```

Comment: can you post you build.sbt/pom.xml with the dependencies?

Comment: It looks like you are using `spark-shell`, which means you should have all your dependencies there for your need. How did you install it and are your running it?

Comment: @RaphaelRoth I have resolved dependencies in POM and I can compile it in eclipse but the error occurs during deployment, i..e executing in scala-shell or as spark-submit jobs

Comment: @stefanobaghino  We had HDP 2.4 & needed new Mllib. We did 1. removed HDP Spark using api. 2. downloaded spark 2.1.1, installed in all machines under /usr/local/spark(SPARK_HOME) 3.Copied hive.xml, core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml to the conf dir. 4.Our spark-env.sh is export SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=18080 export SPARK_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/spark/conf export SPARK_LOG_DIR=/usr/local/spark/logs export SPARK_PID_DIR=${SPARK_HOME}/run export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/hdp/2.4.3.0-227/hadoop/ export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/hdp/2.4.3.0-227/hadoop/conf export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle – Rajesh 10 mins ago